# How do I add a custom annotation to a map view with images in Swift 2?

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, mkannotationview, xcode7.3

I have created an MKMapView, but I need to add multiple annotations with images in Swift 2, how would I do this?

Comment: Go through some tutorials and see this [link](http://www.myswiftjourney.me/2014/10/23/using-mapkit-mkmapview-how-to-create-a-annotation/).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a MKAnnotationView, use this function to create your marker :

```
internal func setupMarker(image:UIImage,long:Double,lat:Double,title:String,subtitle:String) -> MKAnnotationView{
    var pinAnnotationView:MKAnnotationView!
    var pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation!

    pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    pointAnnotation.title = title
    pointAnnotation.subtitle = subtitle
    pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:lat, longitude:long)
    pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    pinAnnotationView.image = image
    pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true

    return pinAnnotationView
}
```

Create your marker:

```
var marker = setupMarker(store.image.image, long: store.location.longitude, lat: store.location.latitude, param: "store",storeId: store.description))
```

Add the marker to your MapView

```
mapView.addAnnotation(marker.annotation!)
```